# What is equivalent of taskset on powershell?

Tags: powershell, multi-core

What is equivalent of taskset on powershell ?

I mean *if you don't know what is taskset*, the command to start a process/application on dedicated pool of CPU cores.

I didn't find anything similar, does it exist that possibility ?
sorry for so basic question but I m out of Windows knowledge.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell you can assign dedicated CPU to a application or process by setting affinity value to the process.

```
Get-Process <ApplicationName> | select -Property ProcessorAffinity
```

For more info for setting the values to process: https://newbedev.com/change-affinity-of-process-with-windows-script

Comment: thanks for that link, this is exactly what I faild to find :)